# Extend interface in types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
interface IType {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    checked?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
interface Category {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    description: string;
}
type Data = Array<{
    name: string;
    label: string;
    description: string;
    types: IType[];
}>;
```

I have the above type descriptions. If you see the `interface Category` has same three keys as in `type Data`. How can I refer the `interface Category` inside my `type Data` without duplicating as I am doing above. Please note that I do not want additional key in my `type Data`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a named interface for the content of the array, which extends Category:

```
interface IType {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    checked?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
interface Category {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    description: string;
}

interface DataItem extends Category {
    types: IType[];
}

type Data = Array<DataItem>;
```

Comment: Definitely this, not least because it makes `Data` largely unnecessary; the OP could just use `DataItem[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal change is to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```
type Data = Array<Category & {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
    types: IType[];
}>;
```

[Live Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUCeAHFBvAKGWORDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMBuIkgGzgCMIOb6jEK3bEEACwgIA1hAAmAfhrcA9io4Q4INiWRzgtHhsXK1GrWwC+BUJFiIUAYTiQmKqJmSFdZSgIbMOpw8fP5CIrpyELQIjNhgwCogYYEE1mA4KAAiLnDIALzIAIJQUHCYADzOru6eAGReosgZuLQ0GJkA2gC6VgB8bARRCFxQKBpgyAAeNDlgcINTnQAM3QB0vhAsxAD0O8gA4mpyBEuray3R23uHx6cr6zBq27v7AKKl7kA)

...but I'd suggest following [JB's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59512437/157247) and creating a type for the contents of that array.

I'd also probably shy away from having a `Data` type at all, but that's a matter of style. If you use a type for the content, you can just use `ThatType[]` where you're currently using `Data`.

Comment: I was going to ask you if you preferred your solution to mine. Except maybe simplicity, is there any advantage or drawback with your/my suggestion?

Comment: @JBNizet - I'm not a TS expert, but for me your solution is better because it means the OP can just use `DataItem[]` and not even bother with a `Data` type (unless they prefer it for style reasons). I'm sure both have a place, but without more info, I'd go your way. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot  @T.J. I'm not a TS expert either. I like it a lot more than JavaScript, but its type system is way more complex than anything else I've used.

Comment: I just wanted to look fancy lol using `type`. Thanks both solution works.